# JavaScript Horizontal Spinner

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, dom

I am making a fun little site for a few of my friends and on thing I wanted to implement was a simple roulette spinner. I started to make some of the assets such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huJPy.png) spinner, but have no idea how to make it look like it is spinning and also land on a specific location.

This is the order in which everything should happen:

1. Every 5 Seconds
   a. Ping server with AJAX including the users amount of points to put in.
   b. Server replies with JSON, two types, {position:"*number*",win:"*true/false*",amount:"*points lost or gained*"}, or {error:"*nospin*"}
   c. This tells us where the roulette table should end at or if it is too early/late to spin

So it will continue to ping until the server tells us that a pick has been made, it will then spin the table to the winning spot and be able to tell the user that, "You lost 1 point!" or "You won 1 point"

Can someone help me accomplish this?

Comment: I suggest using web sockets, try socket.io.

Comment: @YohananBaruchel I am trying to stay away from sockets, if you find a way to answer the question with sockets please do.

Comment: Apparently you already know how you're going to communicate with the server and everything, am I right that you only need help with animating the roulette?

Comment: @Hamsteriffic Yes, Just need help with the animation. But keep in mind that the value changes so it needs to be dynamic in the way that I can tell it where to land with a smooth "spin".

Comment: I see. One idea that comes to my mind is creating a <div> with a fixed width, setting your roulette image as the background-image (that will show cropped since the image is much bigger than the div) and using javascript to dynamically modify the background-position of it every few milliseconds, thus making it look like it's moving.

Comment: @Hamsteriffic That would most likely work, except how should we go about getting the right values for each color? And make look legit (Not in the direct center of each color everytime)

Comment: Let's say each "landing position" has length 50 px, after you know in which spot it should fall, you can generate a random number between 1 and 49 to make it end in a random place. I think I have the whole code in my mind now but I am on my phone so it's hard to type it in :) if you don't mind waiting a few hours, once I get home I'll help you with actual code :)

Comment: @Hamsteriffic Okay, that sounds great! Thank you so much, I'll work on some code too.

Comment: @Hamsteriffic I did some testing with the image I put in the question and it seems like setting a div with the background with the position 0, and adding 70 advances the spinner 1 spot exactly to the left, so subtracting 70 should do the trick. Then varying the ones places and tenths place can add some realism to the spin.

Answer (score 1):

**Idea:** set the roulette image as a background-image of a `<div>` and make the roulette spin by changing the background-position of the div every few milliseconds.

It took me a while, but here you go:

[Working JSFiddle!](https://jsfiddle.net/6g9u1ajf/)

Works nicely, but you probably want to change a few things to make it more realistic. Good luck!